# Get the added/modified/taken date of the video from MediaStore

Tags: android, date, video, mediastore, last-modified

Where do I get the taken date of the video from MediaStore? I got the following fields from MediaStore.

```
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN
MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED
```

Those fields returned seemly default values -

```
dateModified: 1477043336
dateTaken: 1477043336000
dateAdded: 1477043352
```

Formatted dates -

```
dateModified: 01/01/1970
dateTaken: 01/01/1970
dateAdded: 01/01/1970
```

I double checked the stock gallery > random video file and I do see the correct dates. I looked at the video columns in MediaStore and I didn't see any other columns which has correct dates.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)));

    String dateModified = dateFormat.format(new Date(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)));
    String dateTaken = dateFormat.format(new Date(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN) * 1000L));
    String dateAdded = dateFormat.format(new Date(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED) * 1000L));

    Log.d(TAG, "dateModified: "+dateModified);
    Log.d(TAG, "dateTaken: "+dateTaken);
    Log.d(TAG, "dateAdded: "+dateAdded);

    Log.d(TAG, "dateModified: "+row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)));
    Log.d(TAG, "dateTaken: "+row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN)));
    Log.d(TAG, "dateAdded: "+row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED)));
```

Comment: Are you requesting those columns in your query? If you look at the plain numeric values (rather than attempting to format them as dates), what values do you see?

Comment: Yes, I appended the initial post with the raw data from MediaStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Those fields returned seemly default values

I do not know why your second one has three extra zeros at the end. But, using [a Unix date converter site](http://www.epochconverter.com/):

- dateModified = 1477043336 = Fri, 21 Oct 2016 09:48:56 GMT
- dateAdded = 1477043352 = Fri, 21 Oct 2016 09:49:12 GMT

And your `dateTaken`, without the zeros, is the same as `dateModified`. So, assuming you can figure out where your zeros came from (such as by randomly deciding to multiply the value by 1000L), you have valid timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Just multiply it by 1000 to get correct date
     
    fun convertLongToDate(time: Long): String =
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy").format(
                        Instant.ofEpochMilli(time*1000)
                                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                .toLocalDate())
            } else {
                SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(
                        Date(time * 1000)
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the annotations on the interface, `DATE_ADDED` and `DATE_MODIFIED` are annotated as SECONDS since the epoch, rather than milliseconds. `DATE_TAKEN` however is annotated as milliseconds since the epoch.

This difference in annotation explains the differences in zeroes that CommonsWare's answer notes. It also guides usage:

Since date formatters usually expect timestamps in millis, you should multiply second values by 1000 first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function to get actual result of date format.

```
public String getDate(long val){
   val*=1000L;
   return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(val));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntax for convert epoch to normal date in android as follows

```
long date=System.currentTimeMillis(); //current android time in epoch
```

Converts epoch to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" dateformat
Means 1477043336 = 21/10/2016 09:48:56

```
String NormalDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(date));
```